# How to insert data in PHP MariaDB using INSERT...WHERE query

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, sql-insert

I am using phpMariaDB server version-10.1.37. When I use `insert...where` query in code then it is not working.

I hope you solve my problem.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (SNAME,QUALIFICATION,AGE) values('Sumit Kumar','Matric',NOW()) WHERE 'Status'='OK' ;
```

This is the error I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'where Status='OK'' at line 1

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish would help.  Your query simply does not make sense.  `INSERT . . . VALUES` does not take a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need to use `UPDATE` statement in that case because `INSERT` statement doesn't support `WHERE` clause.

Like:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Very very thanks for Answer. I am in problem from two days i have searched in internet everywhere but solution is not seen.